# Excel Office Script - Send data as image

Tags: office365

I have a script that converts a table into an image for Power Automate to email. The script works but it takes an image of the full table (column A,B &C) when i really only need A2:B last row.

One other problem I have is that it doesn't seem to wrap the text in the image like it does on the excel sheet.

Is there someone out there who might be able to help me with these issues?

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): ReportImages {

// Set sheet visibility to ExcelScript.SheetVisibility.visible
let dataSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("DataSheet");
  dataSheet.setVisibility(ExcelScript.SheetVisibility.visible);

// Apply values filter on dataSheet
let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
  table1.getColumnByName("Column3").getFilter().applyValuesFilter(["1"]);

 // Get the data from the table.
let sheet8 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet8");
const table = workbook.getWorksheet('DataSheet').getTables()[0];
const rows = table.getRange().getTexts();

// Create image
const tableImage = table.getRange().getImage();
return { tableImage };
}

// The interface for table
interface ReportImages {
tableImage: string
}
```

Comment: So... by hiding the rows i don't need on the spreadsheet i've been able to create the image without column C. Perfect.

I just can't seem to get it to wrap text in the image now though. It's wrapped on the sheet but the image isn't wrapped. Can anyone offer a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the image data of the table excluding the last column, can you try something like below? Basically this "shrinks" the table range by one column from the right.

```js
...
const tableImage = table.getRange().getResizedRange(0, -1).getImage();
...
```

Regarding the text wrapping, do you mind sharing a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.
"Print_today" - change to your sheet name
"C1:I10503" - change to your range

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): ReportImages {

  // Get the data from the table.
  let print_today = workbook.getWorksheet("Print_today");
  const table = workbook.getWorksheet("Print_today").getRange("C1:I10503")

  // Create image
  const tableImage = table.getImage();
  return { tableImage };
}

// The interface for table
interface ReportImages {
  tableImage: string
}
```

Also you need ad this code as HTML to body of email in Power Automate (but change to your outputs):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,@{outputs('Run_script')?['body/result/tableImage']}"/>
```